# Setting the attribute value of a particular DOM element using Playwright

Tags: playwright, playwright-typescript

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av1dr.png)

I am trying to set the attribute `**src**` value under `<img>` tag to some content. I am using playwright and typescript to change it. Below is the piece of code

```
await this.page.addInitScript(() => {
       window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

          const imageUrl = document.getElementById("'image-" + ImageLandingSteps.IMAGE_ID + "'");
          imageUrl.setAttribute('src','fhfdadsafsdf');
        });
      });
```

I have  attached an image to have a clear picture. basically I am trying the find the Element by id first and then on that I am setting the attribute value

Earlier I used Cypress invoke command on locator to set some attribute value and it worked .

Anything which I am doing incorrectly. Please suggest

Comment: Please share the site and a [mcve] of your code. Your `getElementById` is pretty clearly incorrect since it has extra quotes, it's pointing at a `<div>`, not an `<img>`, and it's unclear where `ImageLandingSteps.IMAGE_ID` is coming from. See also [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen I cant share the site as it internal to our organization, sorry for that. The element in the dom looks like      <div _ngcontent-ng-c726231829="" class="image" id="image-1709930783861i" ng-reflect-ng-class=""><img _ngcontent-ng-c726231829="" alt="" src="https://image-stg-cdn.ncrcloud.com/menu-maker-ui-testing-0c27084fa15f44ef970bbcd18a2ee8ce/image-container/1709930783861i.jpeg?1709930785428">

Comment: @ggorlen , it worked simply by identifying the locator strategy from playwright  and then using evaluate function. Thank you so much for your response !

Answer (score 0):

To do it more Playwright way, you could do it like:

```
const image = page.locator(`#image-${ImageLandingSteps.IMAGE_ID} img`);
await image.evaluate(element => element.setAttribute('src','fhfdadsafsdf'));
```